# how do i compare element of hashset?

Tags: java

```
HashSet<String> noDuplicate = new HashSet<String>();
for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++)
{
     for(int a=0;a<strings2.length;a++)
     {
         if(noDuplicate.get(i).equals(strings2[a]))
             //blahblah code here
     }
}
```

but get doesn't work, i'm not sure how to use iterator if that's the method to use to go through the elements of a hashset. I want to do something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++)
{
     for(int a=0;a<strings2.length;a=a+2)
     {
         if(node_marked_array.get(i).equals(strings2[a]))
             //blahblah code here
     }
}
```

but I was told to use a hashset because of duplicate values.

Comment: I already gave you the code to this in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710668/how-do-i-put-only-unique-values-into-an-array/13710797#13710797

Comment: What do you want to do actually? Do you want to check whether some `Set` contains values from `strings` array? Or what?

Comment: yes that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: Is my answer applicable? If not, comment me to adjust it. I've just copied your code and used correct method for `Set`.

Comment: I cannot figure out what you trying to do. What is all for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HashSet#contains` instead:

```
HashSet<String> noDuplicate = new HashSet<String>();
for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++){
    for(int a=0;a<strings2.length;a++){
         if(noDuplicate.contains(strings2[a]))
         //blahblah code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Set`s have no order by definition, and therefore can't be indexed like arrays, or lists via a `get` method. However you can still iterate through the elements of a `Set` with a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop (or by using the iterator returned by the `iterator()` method).

For example, if I had a `Set` called `set` which contained strings `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"`:

```
for (String s : set) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Not having order has nothing to do with not having a `get()` method. See `HashMap` for counter-example.

Comment: @EJP I've clarified the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose this will help

```
    Iterator iter=hm.keySet().iterator();
           while(iter.hasNext()){ 
              String key = (String)iter.next();
             if(key.equals(str)){
                  val1 = (String)hm.get(key);
               }
           }
```